# AngularDart 5 and Firebase deployment

Tags: firebase, dart, angular-dart

I’m trying to deploy my AngularDart 5 web app to Firebase. These are the steps I followed:

1. I builded my app with the command `pub run build_runner build --output build`.
2. I launched the command `firebase init` and setted `web` folder as the public folder.
3. I deployed my web app with the command `firebase deploy`.

⚠ The **problem** is that when I open the website I find only a *blank page*.

❔ What I’m doing wrong?

Thank you!

---

Yes, I am still having this issue. The content of my `firebase.json` is:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don’t know if it helps, but my `pubspec.yaml` file is:

```
name: angular_app
description: Angular App
version: 0.0.1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.63.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  sass_builder: ^2.0.2
  angular: ^5.0.0-alpha+15
  angular_forms: ^2.0.0-alpha+7
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+14

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0-alpha+13
  build_runner: ^0.8.9
  build_test: ^0.10.2+5
  build_web_compilers: ^0.4.0+4
  test: ^1.0.0
```

When I deploy on **firebase** or when I serve the app with `firebase serve`, I see only “Loading...”.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I’m sorry, I forgot to write one step in my question post: 4. Deploy with `firebase deploy`. The result is the same: a *blank page*.

Comment: If you serve with [webdev](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdev), can you view your app in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can see my app there.

Comment: Good, then we know that the app isn't the issue. See my questions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your step 3, you need to use `firebase deploy` to deploy rather than pub.
- In your `firebase.json` file, the `hosting.public` entry shown above is just `"web"` but your build output directory is "build". The entry should probably be "build/web".
- Are you setting `<base href>` in your `index.html`? If so, to which `href` value?
- You wrote that when you serve you only see “Loading...”. Open then JavaScript console. Do you see any error messages?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it doesn’t change anything.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, what is the content of your `firebase.json` config file?

Comment: Yes, below I will show you the content of my `firebase.json` file.

Comment: Yes, I still have the same issue. I have update my question. Thanks!

Comment: After I changed `hosting.public` entry from just `web` entry to `build/web`, **firebase** serves my app without any problem. Thank you *very* much!