# Firebase and AngularDart. Error: There was an issue preparing Hosting files for upload

Tags: firebase, dart, angular-dart, firebase-hosting

I’m trying to host my web app in **Firebase**. I runned:

1. `webdev build --output build`,
2. `firebase init`, and
3. `firebase deploy`,

but I received a error message:

```
Error: There was an issue preparing Hosting files for upload.
```

So I runned `firebase deploy --debug`. The error message was:

```
i  hosting: preparing build/web directory for upload...
[2018-08-11T14:30:25.054Z] Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat 'C:\Users\marco\MyWebApp\WEB\WEBSITE
- Copia\build\web\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages\packages'

Error: There was an issue preparing Hosting files for upload.
```

How can I resolve this error?

(If I run `firebase serve`, it works).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using symlinks in your content directory, as the error message suggests?  What exactly does your `web` folder contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627558/3046255), ensure that in the `firebase.json` file you've set the `hosting.public` field to `"build/web"`:

```
{
  "hosting": { "public": "build/web" }
}
```

There seems to be an [issue with webdev builds](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1751) at the moment (unless it is a firebase issue). Anyhow, as a workaround, I found that deleting the symlink that causes the loop (`build/packages/packages`) solved the issue for me.

From the **root of your project** run this command **every time** you rerun **`webdev build -o build`**:

```
  rm build/packages/packages
```

After that both `firebase serve` and `firebase deploy` worked for me.